# Flask gives IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory

Tags: python, flask

### IsADirectoryError

`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/abrarwali/PycharmProjects/xyz/EmailApp/attachments'`

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.getcwd() + '/EmailApp', 'attachments')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


files = request.files.getlist('attachment')

for file in files:
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        file_name = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']),file_name)
```

I don't follow because `save` accepts a destination directory which I'm supplying and the filename to save. I have gone through StackOverflow solutions but I'm unable to fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was typo, there is an extra and a missing `)` in

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']),file_name)
```

it should be

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],file_name))
```